# 301 Redirect for Non-Date Based URL's

Tags: permalinks, redirect, date

I'm wanting to redirect posts in WordPress that do not have a date based permalink structure to those that do. For example:

domain/aprils-obx-race-recap-gnarly to: domain/2014/07/09/april-s-obx-race-recap-gnarly/

I should be able to do it with something like this right:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /20(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ http://www.mydomain.com/$3
```

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: I think you can't do that at .htaccess level. I you have a URL without date permalink structure, How can you know the date to construct the redirection URL when the .htaccess file is reached and no code have been executed in your website? You need to do it in PHP/Wordpress.

Comment: Good point... I was thinking maybe it would be able to somehow point to what _could_ be the date or at least search for a possible date string (rather than not at all) being that all the posts now have the date in permalink.